# Changing index.html refuse to take place in actual running of a web application 

Tags: java, html, jsp, web-applications, servlets

Something very weird is happening when I try to edit my `index.html` file .

I'm working with `jsp`-s and `servlets` , in Java.

When I try to update one of the fields , for instance :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Bank application</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="./css/styles.css"
      type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<table class="title">
  <tr><th>Bank application</th></tr>
</table>

<br/>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Bank Account Balance</legend>
  <form action="show-balance">
    Customer ID (id001, idffffffffffffffffdsafds002, id003):
    <input type="text" name="cusdddddddddddddddddddddddddddtomerId"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Sddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddhow Balance"/>
  </form>
</fieldset>

<br/>

// from here, the rest is the same as the above
```

I get this (same as before) :

[image]

Why when changing the index.html file , no change takes place ?

I'm using :

1. Apache 7
2. Xampp

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers will cache HTML files unless you explicitly tell the browser to refresh (ctrl + F5).  I'm guessing you're just loading the cached version of the HTML.